# Is ajax faster than targetting in iframe

Tags: ajax, performance, iframe

I have used both ajax as well as targetting in iframe.
Can anycody tell me which is faster.

Answer (score 1):

From this ajax plugin: [malsup form](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/), you can try both ajax form, then decide which one better suits you and iframe for the same form, here is an example:

```
$("#your-form-id").ajaxForm({ 
//iframe: true //this goes with iframe 
success: function (responseText, statusText, req, $form) 
                { $("#target-div-id").html(responseText);  } });
```

Ajax is used unless you have to file upload then you can use iframe, that imitates ajax form.